# Selenium2 HtmlUnitDriver fill form incorrectly

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I use HtmlUnitDriver to fill form with some arabic words like this :

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://example.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("id_message")).sendKeys("Some arabic words here");
driver.findElement(By.id("submit-button")).click();
```

it fill text input with id : id_message with question marks like this :

> ?????? ????? ???? ???? ???? ???? ??? ?? ???? ???? ??? ????? ? ?????
>   ??????? ?????? ??? ????? ?????? ???? ????? ??? ???

How can I solve this problem ?